Is it possible to alter or replace the onChange function of an input within the InspectorControls panel?
I am writing a plugin and attempting to alter what attribute gets updated when changing the value of an input in the editor sidepanel. I am filtering a function through editor.BlockEdit using wp.compose.createHigherOrderComponent. I am able to do something like below to add to the 'dimensions' (margin and padding) panel:
return (
  <Fragment>
    <BlockEdit {...props} />
    {isSelected && props.name === "core/paragraph" && (
      <InspectorControls group="dimensions">
        <TextControl 
            label="Custom input"
            value={value}          
            onChange={value => setAttribute('myAttribute', value)}
           />
        </InspectorControls>
     )}
  </Fragment>
);

In theory this will update my custom attribute 'myAttribute' when the TextControl changes. Within the dimensions panel there's existing TextControl inputs which update the style.spacing attributes. Am I able to filter/hook into/alter in any way the functionality of the existing TextControls' onChange so I could, say, update style.myAttribute instead of the default attribute?

what are you trying to implement that requires this? There's likely a much better way of doing it that avoids this issue, what you're asking about is likely going to cause problems and future breakage. What's the reason for having myAttribute when core already has an attribute for it?
